# Whoosh: shouldn't OR only increase results?

Tags: python, search-engine, django-haystack, whoosh

We have about 9k documents indexed using Haystack 1.2.7 with Whoosh 2.4.1 as backend. Despite of using Haystack, it looks like a Whoosh problem. Take a look at my debug cases:

1) If I just run an exact lookup, Whoosh finds my document (as below):

```
>>> SearchQuerySet().all().models(PedidoSaida).filter(numero__exact='6210202443/10')
[<SearchResult: logistica.pedidosaida (pk=u'6')>]
```

2) If I just run a startswith lookup, Whoosh doesn't find my document (as below):

```
>>> SearchQuerySet().all().models(PedidoSaida).filter(numero__startswith='6210202443/10')
[]
```

3) If I put all together in a single OR query, Whoosh still doesn't find my document (as below):

```
>>> SearchQuerySet().all().models(PedidoSaida).filter(SQ(numero__exact='6210202443/10') | SQ(numero__startswith='6210202443/10'))
[]
```

Taking a look into the queries that Haystack sends to Whoosh, we have:

```
>>> str(SearchQuerySet().all().models(PedidoSaida).filter(numero__exact='6210202443/10').query)                                       
'(numero:6210202443/10) AND (django_ct:logistica.pedidosaida)'

>>> str(SearchQuerySet().all().models(PedidoSaida).filter(numero__startswith='6210202443/10').query)
'(numero:6210202443/10*) AND (django_ct:logistica.pedidosaida)'

>>> str(SearchQuerySet().all().models(PedidoSaida).filter(SQ(numero__exact='6210202443/10') | SQ(numero__startswith='6210202443/10')).query)
'((numero:6210202443/10 OR numero:6210202443/10*)) AND (django_ct:logistica.pedidosaida)'
```

As you can observe, the last query is exactly (first OR second). Shouldn't Whoosh find my document? I can't see where my logic is wrong: I'm using OR and it is finding less than when I use one of the statements.

I also think it is weird that Whoosh finds my document with the first query (numero:6210202443/10), but not with the second (numero:6210202443/10*) one. But I guess it has to do with StemmingAnalyzer that Haystack uses in my CharField. I'll take a deep look into that after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `QueryParser` directly to see how Whoosh is parsing that query:

```
>>> from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
>>> QueryParser("content", schema=None).parse('((numero:6210202443/10 OR numero:6210202443/10*)) AND (django_ct:logistica.pedidosaida)')
And([Or([Term('numero', '6210202443/10'), Term('numero', '6210202443/')]), Prefix('content', '10'), Term('django_ct', 'logistica.pedidosaida')])
```

Let's reformat that last line:

```
And([
    Or([
        Term('numero', '6210202443/10'),
        Term('numero', '6210202443/'),
    ]),
    Prefix('content', '10'),
    Term('django_ct', 'logistica.pedidosaida'),
])
```

So it looks like `*` is binding more tightly than the `/` in your search term.  I could see arguing this as a bug in whoosh, sure.  (I'm sure the maintainer would love your patch  ☺)

Workarounds coming to mind:

1. Build the query yourself instead of round-tripping through Whoosh's fuzzily-defined and human-oriented query language.  Of course, that only works if your index is on the same machine and you're reading it with the same process; I don't know much about Haystack.
2. Avoid using slashes in the `numero` field.  Change them to something less likely to look like query syntax, like underscores.
3. Avoid including the slash when you do a prefix search; for example, `6210202443*` works fine anywhere in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Eevee ideas, I did some tests. Check this one:

```
>>> QueryParser("content", schema=None).parse('((numero:6210202443/10 OR (numero:6210202443/10*))) AND (django_ct:logistica.pedidosaida)')
And([
    Or([
        Term('numero', '6210202443/10'), 
        And([
            Term('numero', '6210202443/'), 
            Prefix('content', '10')
        ])
    ]), 
    Term('django_ct', 'logistica.pedidosaida')
])
```

It seems that `/` has precedence over `OR`. Does it make sense? I think that logical operators should have highest precedence. Do you agree?

If this behaviour is correct than I guess it is a bug in Haystack query generator. Isn't it?

I want to contribute with a patch but I'm not sure if it is really a bug in the parser. Depends on precedence that makes more sense.

Comment: this should really be an edit to the question  :)  but i've contributed some patches to whoosh, and in my experience the maintainer is very responsive; i'd either [file a ticket](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/issues?status=new&status=open) or just optimistically write the patch and send it as a pull request.